# Creating a Facebook Secret Group via the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am a bit stumped by this. I am trying to create a 'secret group' using the Facebook graph API, but it doesn't seem to work. I am getting the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Invalid parameter", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

I am able to create an `open` and `closed` group, but `secret` doesn't seem to be working.

The [documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/app-game-groups#create_group) tells me that this should be working just fine, however I've come across [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app-game-groups) which makes no mention of secret groups.

So I am wondering whether there is something I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option seem to be missing from the v2.2 API.

According to the link as you stated the only two options are closed or open.
privacy : ( The privacy setting for the group. )
enum{ closed, open }

It is not even possible to change the group to Secret after it has been created, not by API or as group admin.

According to Developers of the v2.2 API, supporting only Open/Closed is by design:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1511921725716006